# How to Reduce the size of camera source in mobile vision API text detection

Tags: android, text, detection, android-vision

As google vision api text detection previews full screen to scan text. I want a small rectangle for text detection and display the recognized text below in a textbox

Answer (score 1):

You can control the size of the preview widget.
Change this line https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/ocr-reader/app/src/main/res/layout/ocr_capture.xml#L12 to whatever you want.

This is the Android documentation about the possible values you can use for `layout_width` and `layout_height` properties https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html

Comment: I have already done it. but the camera is still recognizing the text which is not in the preview area.

Comment: i want to reduce the area of camerapreview and also i want to capture only the text within the area by the camera.

Comment: i have reduced the camera preview area. but camera is capturing the full area and recognizing text..... I want only that text to be recognized which is within the preview

Comment: You mean like a ROI(region of interest)? No vision API doesn't support that now.